# How to filter a nested Json with occasionally subcatagories and different types with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a json result from facebook with occasionally a subattachment and I can't seem to access the subattachment to show all the photo's.

Here is a Json example (adjusted it, so it wasn't so long:

```
{
"data":[
    {
    "id":"1"
    "type":"video",
    "attachments":{
        "data":[
                {
                "media":{
                    "image":{
                        "src":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t15.0-10\/s720x720\/"
                        }
                    }
                }   
            ]
        }
    },
    {
    "id":"2"
    "type":"photo",
    "attachments":{
        "data":[
                {
                "media":{
                    "image":{
                        "src":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-0\/q84\/p180x540\/"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
    "id":"3"
    "type":"photo",
    "attachments":{
        "data":[
            {
            "subattachments":{
                "data":[
                    {
                    "media":{
                        "image":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/s720x720\/"
                        }
                        }
                    "type":"photo"
                    },                  
                    {
                    "media":{
                        "image":{
                            "src":"https:\/\/scontent.xx.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/s720x720\/"
                        }
                    },
                    "type":"video"
                    }
                ]
            }
            "type":"album",
            }
            ]
        }
    }
]}
```

This is what i  so far:

```
$json_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$page_id}/feed?access_token={$access_token}&fields={$fields}";
$json = file_get_contents($json_link);
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

When I try:

```
if(isset($obj->data)) {
    foreach ($obj->data as $key => $value)
    {
        $attachments =  $value->attachments->data[0];
        $att = $attachments->media->image->src;
        $images = explode('&url=',$att);

        if(isset($images))
        {   
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="error" /><br>';
            }
        }

        for($i=0;$i<count($value->attachments->data[0]);$i++)
        {
            $subattachments = $attachments->subattachments->data[$i];
            $subatt = $subattachments->media->image->src;
            $subimages = explode('&url=',$subatt);

            foreach ($subimages as $subimage) {
                echo '<img src="' . $subimage . '" alt="error" /><br>';
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

This shows all the photo,s in the attachments, but throws several errors, because the code wants to show the subattachments in the attachments also. How do I filter this, so I don't get any errors?

It also shows just 1 photo in the subattachments. How can I show all the photo's in the subattachments? I tried it with if and if else statements and for loops, for each loops. I can't get it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: The problem is most likely the `for` loop. Instead try a simple foreach like this: `foreach ($value->attachments->data as $subattachment) { ... }`

Comment: I get 2 of the same photo's now with the foreach loop. Tried it within the for loop and result is the same. 2 of the same photo's. I don't know why it only returns the $attachments->subattachments->data[0]. What do I do with data[?]?

Comment: The 0 in the square brackets shows the index or offset. In your example above the item with id=3 has 3 subattachments. So they should be accessible with the data[0], data[1], data[2]. Since you do `count($value->attachments->data[0])` in the for loop it will access the first subattachment and count the number of properties which is 2 ("media":..., "type":...). It looks like you are re-using the offset from attachments for subattachments. This might be where the error is coming from.